# iOS app crash after UITextField text entry, pop, then push on my navController (NSISObjectiveLinearExpression coefficientForVariable)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unrecognized-selector

My iOS app crashes when I:

- present my "Login" view controller in a navigation controller
- enter text into a `UITextField` on it, then try and fail the login
- pop back to the above view controller
- push to a different view controller (crashes here)

It **doesn't** crash if I skip the step where I enter text into the `UITextField`.

Does anyone have any idea why? Here is the error message I am getting.

`[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression coefficientForVariable:]: unrecognized
selector sent to instance 0x1cd93850`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem too. Using ARC, I would get this crash if I added a `UITextField` to an otherwise empty xib and, after editing the field, popped its view controller of the navigation controller's stack. The text field had no delegate set and no outlets connected to it. And yet it was crashing!

(If your situation was like mine, you weren't instantiating a `NSISObjectiveLinearExpression` as mydogisbox suggests. )

After much searching, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066777/168594), which suggests calling `endEditing:` in your `viewWillDisappear` method. It appeared to fix my crash.

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];
    NSLog( @"In viewWillDisappear" );
    // Force any text fields that might be being edited to end so the text is stored
    [self.view.window endEditing: YES];
}
```