# iOS app crashes when changing view while editing a UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, uitextfield

I am learning Swift with Xcode 6 and have encountered a problem.
When the user edits a `UITextField` (keyboard visible) and then goes back a view using the Navigation Controls the app terminates with `'uncaught exception of type NSException'`.

Possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319144/ios-app-crash-after-uitextfield-text-entry-pop-then-push-on-my-navcontroller) is the same problem, only I am using Swift instead of Objective-C so I could not use that solution. Can anyone help me with a solution in Swift?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not sure what code would be helpful with this issue. I only have some functions for editing an array...

Comment: Post the class with the UITextField and the class you are going back to.  This way we can see if the problem is with the UITextField containing class, or the segue.