# Crash when UIPopoverViewController dismisses with UITextField first responder

Tags: keyboard, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller

Whenever my popover is dismissed by touching in another view when keyboard is shown for a UITextField, my app crashes with this error -

`[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression coefficientForVariable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd93850`

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061788/storing-uitextfield-contents-before-view-pops), explaining that I should `endEditing` in `viewWillDisappear`, but it didn't help, while debugging it crashes before even getting to `viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover` is called at the `UIPopoverViewControllerDelegate` before the crash, so I've planted `endEditing` over there and it worked.

This is the delegate's code -

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [self.view.window endEditing: YES];

    return YES;
}
```